# Significado de la palabra inundo en esta frase

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

Me encontré con la siguiente frase: "De vez en cuando, mientras alguien abandona la larga procesión de buscadores, el **inundo** recibe la moticia de que otra persona ha logrado triunfar en Broadway, pero conquistarlo no es fácil ni rápido"

Qué significa "inundo" en esta oración? Busqué en el dicionario y solo se relaciona con inundar pero no me parece que sea el significado en este contexto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tras una búsqueda en Google, parece que la frase se ha transcrito de forma errada, así donde dice *inundo* debe decir *mundo*. Suele ocurrir con los libros digitales, donde algunas palabras no se *transcriben* de forma adecuada a partir del escaneo.

Pero volviendo a tu pregunta, quedaría de la siguiente forma

> "(...) mientras alguien abandona la larga procesión de buscadores, el **mundo** recibe la noticia de que otra persona (...)"

Como extra, me atrevería a decir que la oración viene con un caso de dequeísmo: (debería usarse *(...) la noticia **que** otra persona (...)* en lugar de *(...) la noticia **de que** otra persona (...)*) pero no estoy seguro...

Comment: "La noticia que" y "la noticia de que" son ambas correctas, pero tienen usos diferentes. Por ejemplo:
_La noticia que_ leí ayer me dejó preocupado.
_La noticia de que_ subían los precios me dejó preocupado.

Comment: Para mí tiene más sentido la segunda forma en este caso.